# expected identifier error in xcode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

i get this error "expected identifier before 'OBJC_STRING' token" on this line of code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)@"Landscape.xib" bundle:(NSBundle *)mainBundle {
```

and im not sure why, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In method declaration you can't use string literals for parameter name.  Declare it

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)mainBundle {
...
```

and pass `@"Landscape.xib"` as parameter when call that method

P.S. not sure if that's relevant to your question or not, but just in case - objective-c does not support default values for function parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a string in like that.  You would use:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)mainBundle {

...

}
```

and call it from some other line of code like this:

```
[[Class alloc] initWithNibName:@"Landscape.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```